# Can't find the denoiser in view layer

Tags: rendering, denoise, noise-reduction

I am using Cycles and yet it doesn't appear.

[image]

It doesn't work even when I'm using the denoiser node.

[image]

please any advice would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The option is hidden in the `Viewer Layer Properties` panel. There you will find the `Denoising Data` checkbox. (In Blender 2.9x it's under Passes → Data.) Tick the checkbox and the Render Layers node will get some extra sockets for the Denoise node.

[image: denoising data checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

"Denoiser" in [View Layer Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/view_layer.html) was moved to Data--> Denoising Data as mentioned above, and it works.

Additionally, for Cycles Renders (starting in Blender 2.81 onward) there is now a Denoising *Filter* that can be editing in the [Compositor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html), which does a wonderful job Denoising in Renders where the "Data--> Denoising Data" still renders with noise.

Zach Reinhardt did a walkthrough comparing/contrasting both denoiser options in this tutorial: [Denoising in Blender Cycles Rendering](https://youtu.be/THgQ5t5WIMw?t=766)